# Jenkins Embeddable Build Status plugin gets redirected due to SSO

Tags: github, jenkins, markdown, single-sign-on

I'm trying to add Jenkins build status using the [Embeddable Build Status plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/embeddable-build-status/) onto Github `README.md` file. I have SSO for Github and Jenkins and I assumed it will have the login info in the browser cookies or wherever it stored that info but looks like it doesn't work that way (The same URL works and picks up SSO info and doesn't prompt me when I open it from a browser. It just doesn't like Github pulling that info)

I see a `302 redirect` on the Jenkins status badge link that is getting redirected to the SSO page and is expecting JS to be enabled for it to work which isn't possible on a Github `README.md` page (Even if that was possible I would not see a login prompt)

The console has a warning for this redirected URL request as `Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response <the-URL> with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.`

I also set the Jenkins config to `ViewStatus` for anonymous uses based on [JENKINS-17798](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-17798) and I'm using the unprotected link but it still needs SSO

Is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: hi can you share your `CORS Filter` setting from your jenkins installation??

Comment: @SiddharthKaul where do I find that info? but I think this issue is related to the SSO as a security realm

Answer (score 0):

Read this first. [Cors-Filter Plugin for Jenkins](https://plugins.jenkins.io/cors-filter/).
Before you go debugging. First make sure that CORS is enabled for the Jenkins instance. You can go to configure system in jenkins and then to CORS Filter:

[image]

A very short summary.

1. Access-Control-Allow-Origins - List domains that may access the jenkins url.
2. Access-Control-Allow-Headers - Headers that can be used to make actual request
3. Access-Control-Expose-Headers - List of headers browser are allowed to access.

Whenever one tries to go authenticating from one domain to another it usually gets redirected in jenkins if CORS Filter is not active. So try this first.

Comment: I will give this a try but do you think SSO should not prompt a user to login in the first place cause it has view enabled for anonymous users? So would it be an SSO issue in the first place?